# How to show opencv projectedPoints on an image

Tags: c++, opencv, display, point-clouds

The goal of the following code is to project the corner vertices of a cube, and the center point, onto a camera image plane.  However, the image created contains a copy of the background screen, and does not display the 9 cube points, or at least I don't see any of the nine points.  If this code was working, what I'm trying to understand is the  influence of the  rotation and translation vectors arguments on the view of cube.  What I would like to do is rotate the camera around the cube while looking at the cube.  P.S. any information on the mathematics of the projection of 3D points onto a 2d camera image plane would be helpful too.  PPS.  It would also be helpful to number the vertices in order to make the image clearer.

```
// baseline: https://www.programmersought.com/article/6279272931/
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/viz/types.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

vector<cv::Point3f> Generate3DPoints();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Generate 3D points
    vector<cv::Point3f> objectPoints = Generate3DPoints();
    vector<cv::Point2f> imagePoints;

    // Camera settings
    cv::Mat intrisicMat(3, 3, cv::DataType<float>::type); // Intrisic matrix
    intrisicMat.at<float>(0, 0) = 1.6415318549788924e+003;
    intrisicMat.at<float>(1, 0) = 0;
    intrisicMat.at<float>(2, 0) = 0;

    intrisicMat.at<float>(0, 1) = 0;
    intrisicMat.at<float>(1, 1) = 1.7067753507885654e+003;
    intrisicMat.at<float>(2, 1) = 0;

    intrisicMat.at<float>(0, 2) = 5.3262822453148601e+002;
    intrisicMat.at<float>(1, 2) = 3.8095355839052968e+002;
    intrisicMat.at<float>(2, 2) = 1;

    // Rotation vector
    cv::Mat rVec(3, 1, cv::DataType<float>::type); 
    rVec.at<float>(0) = -3.9277902400761393e-002;
    rVec.at<float>(1) = 3.7803824407602084e-002;
    rVec.at<float>(2) = 2.6445674487856268e-002;

    // Translation vector
    cv::Mat tVec(3, 1, cv::DataType<float>::type); 
    tVec.at<float>(0) = 2.1158489381208221e+000;
    tVec.at<float>(1) = -7.6847683212704716e+000;
    tVec.at<float>(2) = 2.6169795190294256e+001;

    // Distortion vector
    cv::Mat distCoeffs(5, 1, cv::DataType<float>::type);   
    distCoeffs.at<float>(0) = -7.9134632415085826e-001;
    distCoeffs.at<float>(1) = 1.5623584435644169e+000;
    distCoeffs.at<float>(2) = -3.3916502741726508e-002;
    distCoeffs.at<float>(3) = -1.3921577146136694e-002;
    distCoeffs.at<float>(4) = 1.1430734623697941e-002;

    cout << "Intrisic matrix: " << intrisicMat << endl << endl;
    cout << "Rotation vector: " << rVec << endl << endl;
    cout << "Translation vector: " << tVec << endl << endl;
    cout << "Distortion coef: " << distCoeffs << endl << endl;

    // Generate the points as viewed from the camera
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> projectedPoints;
    cv::projectPoints(objectPoints, rVec, tVec, intrisicMat, distCoeffs, projectedPoints);

    // Display the points in an image
    cv::Mat image(480, 640, CV_8UC3);
    const uint black_r(0), black_g(0), black_b(0);
    const uint silver_r(192), silver_g(192), silver_b(192);
    // image = cv::Scalar(redVal,greenVal,blueVal);
    image = cv::Scalar(black_b, black_g, black_r);
    // cv::viz::COLOR blk(cv::viz::Color::black());
    cv::Vec3b color(silver_b, silver_g, silver_r);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < projectedPoints.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << "Project point " << objectPoints[i] << " to " << projectedPoints[i];
        cv::Point2f pt = projectedPoints[i];
        if (0<= (pt.x) && (pt.x) <= image.cols && 0<= (-pt.y) && (-pt.y) <= image.rows )
        {
            unsigned int ix(std::floor(pt.x)), iy(std::ceil(-pt.y));
            cout << ", and set image.at(" << ix << ", " << iy << ") = " << color;
            image.at<cv::Vec3b>(ix, iy) = color;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "calling imshow" << endl;
    cv::namedWindow("Projection", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::imshow("Projection", image);
    cout << "return from imshow" << endl;

    cout << "Press any key to exit.";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}

vector<cv::Point3f> Generate3DPoints()
{
    vector<cv::Point3f> points;

    float x, y, z;

    // 8 corners of a cube

    // +0.5 z face
    z = .5;
    x = .5; y = .5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3f(x, y, z));
    y = -.5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3f(x, y, z));
    x = -.5; y = .5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3f(x, y, z));
    y = -.5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3f(x, y, z));

    // -0.5 z face
    z = -.5;
    x = .5; y = .5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3f(x, y, z));
    y = -.5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3f(x, y, z));
    x = -.5; y = .5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3f(x, y, z));
    y = -.5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3f(x, y, z));

    // mid point
    x = 0; y = 0; z = 0;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3f(x, y, z));

    return points;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

#### 1. Mismatch between image size and camera intrinsic params

From `intrisicMat` you can see that the principle point is `(532.63, 380.95)`. So the image size should be about `1000*800`, but the image you used is only `640*480`. In fact, 5 in 9 points are project out of the image area (x>640).

#### 2. Drawing positions wrong

The arguments of `cv::Mat::at()` is `(row, col)`, so
`image.at<cv::Vec3b>(ix, iy)` should be changed to `image.at<cv::Vec3b>(iy, ix)`

#### 3. `cv::waitKey()`

You should call `cv::waitKey(0);` after `cv::imshow()`， otherwise you won't see the image.

With these problems fixed, you will see the projected 9 points.

Comment: Thank you!  I am self taught, and still making beginner errors...